# Notify Activity for Multiple Notification Feeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, getstream-io

I'm setting up a notification feed for users to get notified when they receive comments on an item associated with them, but I dont think the stream-rails gem supports notification of multiple feeds.

What I've been using:

```
def activity_notify
  [StreamRails.client.feed('Notification', self.commentable.user.id)]
end
```

Except this only notifies one user. I actually need it to loop through ALL users related to the object:

- Other users who have commented on the object (`Jack commented on something you've recently commented on`)
- Other users who have liked the object ('Jack commented on something you've recently liked`)
- And finally a conditional so you dont get a notification about commenting on your own object (`You just commented on your own object`)

Would the best thing to do here be to define my own method and push to each feed manually?

```
def notify_related_users
  users = users_who_also_commented

  users.each do |user|
    feed = StreamRails.client.feed('Notification', self.commentable.user.id)
    activity_data = build_activity
    feed.create_activity(activity_data)
  end
end
```

This isnt glamorous in the least but it should theoretically get the job done right? Is there an alternative to do something with `activity_notify` and pass in multiple feeds like so:

```
def activity_notify
  [StreamRails.client.feed('Notification', 1),
   StreamRails.client.feed('Notification', 2),
   StreamRails.client.feed('Notification', 3)
  ]
end
```

Comment: Hi Jeff. Have you looked at your data explorer on the dashboard to see what's actually being written to your notification feeds when you execute this code? There's also a lower-level stream-ruby call you can make to add a single activity to multiple feeds, https://github.com/GetStream/stream-ruby/blob/cfdb307a7ab5f0d264548545abcb175e059d9a9c/lib/stream/batch.rb#L28-L42

Comment: I havent seen it but I have manually added an activity using the `create_activity` function. It seems like the method you linked would be very useful in uploading to a "batched feed". This would be my go-to answer in this case unless `activity_notify` also supports multiple feeds

Comment: You'll need load up the 'to' attribute of the base activity, which is a list of other feeds where you want to send that activity. https://github.com/GetStream/stream-rails/blob/2b72cfb074e74791d4159427af395e70bb88b193/lib/stream_rails/activity.rb#L97